# Error while building : Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Everything was woing Great, getting ready to test APK on diferent devices, but now, when i try to build, gave me this error:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Kaiser

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Diego\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\\res\\layout\\list_preference_layout.xml","position":{"startLine":11}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\Diego\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\\res\\layout\\list_preference_layout.xml:12: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/icon' for external package 'android'.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Diego\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\\res\\layout\\list_preference_layout.xml","position":{"startLine":31}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\Diego\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\\res\\layout\\list_preference_layout.xml:32: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/summary' for external package 'android'.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Diego\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\\res\\layout\\list_preference_layout.xml","position":{"startLine":25}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\Diego\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\\res\\layout\\list_preference_layout.xml:26: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/title' for external package 'android'.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Diego\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\\res\\layout\\list_preference_layout.xml","position":{"startLine":42}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\Diego\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\\res\\layout\\list_preference_layout.xml:43: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/widget_frame' for external package 'android'.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Diego\\Desktop\\Kaiser\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_main.xml","position":{"startLine":9}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\Diego\\Desktop\\Kaiser\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_main.xml:10: AAPT: error: resource drawable/mas (aka com.kaiser:drawable/mas) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Diego\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\res\layout\list_preference_layout.xml:12: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/icon' for external package 'android'.
         
     C:\Users\Diego\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\res\layout\list_preference_layout.xml:32: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/summary' for external package 'android'.
         
     C:\Users\Diego\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\res\layout\list_preference_layout.xml:26: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/title' for external package 'android'.
         
     C:\Users\Diego\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\42c451172659b686dff6601c1a023c68\jetified-ui_legacy-8.12.0\res\layout\list_preference_layout.xml:43: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/widget_frame' for external package 'android'.
         
     C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Kaiser\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:10: AAPT: error: resource drawable/mas (aka com.kaiser:drawable/mas) not found.
         

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
8 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 7 up-to-date
```

i've allready try "Clean & Rebuild Project", "Invalidate Cache and Restart", "Deleting the cache folder under .gradle"  "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m  on the Grade.Property", "Advanved profiling is Disable"

I'm out of ideas (Except, maybe to burn the entire building down.. :( )

Comment: You must have changed something in the resources like a layout or other resource, maybe deleted something. Have a look.

Comment: @AdnanTemur that was it. I've delated a couple of images from the Drawable folder, that wasn't beeing use, but it seems like the were...Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is important to be careful when making changes to the resources, otherwise a minor change can lead to a build crash and it gets difficult to find out which resource it is related to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open all your xml files and see if there are any errors. Fix the errors then run again. It took my hours to figure it out.